Swiper проблема с AJAX, observe не работает
есть витрина товаров, на каждом карточке есть несколько фото, вот для каждой карточки настроен слайдер
под карточки есть кнопка Показать еще, по клику отображается еще несколько карточек с картинками через AJAX
у меня gulp сборщик, вот код инициализации свайпер
включил функцию observe и его дочерные, родители и т.д, но на новых карточках не работает свайпер
const additionalProductImages = new Swiper(".additional__product-images", {
modules: [Pagination],
speed: 1500,
loop: true,
pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
},
lazy: {
    loadOnTransitionStart: false,
    loadPrevNext: true,
}

});
также добавил код инициализации свайпер в функцию, по клику на кнопку Показать еще, вызвал эту функцию, но все еще не работает
как можно решить такую задачу
